# Ubuntu 14.10 gstreamer 1.4.3 h264parse missing?

Tags: 14.10, gstreamer

Hello I just upgraded my OS from 14.04 to 14.10 I was thrilled when I saw new version of gstreamer but the problem is that h264parse element is missing. I tried to reinstall gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad but nothing. When I use decodebin it's automatically using vaapiparse_h264 and I got this error when I try to run pipeline:

Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...

```
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request

** (gst-launch-1.0:17411): CRITICAL **: gst_vaapi_image_get_plane: assertion 'image != NULL' failed

** (gst-launch-1.0:17411): CRITICAL **: gst_vaapi_image_get_pitch: assertion 'image != NULL' failed

** (gst-launch-1.0:17411): CRITICAL **: gst_vaapi_image_get_plane: assertion 'image != NULL' failed

** (gst-launch-1.0:17411): CRITICAL **: gst_vaapi_image_get_pitch: assertion 'image != NULL' failed

** (gst-launch-1.0:17411): CRITICAL **: gst_vaapi_image_get_plane: assertion 'image != NULL' failed

** (gst-launch-1.0:17411): CRITICAL **: gst_vaapi_image_get_pitch: assertion 'image != NULL' failed

** (gst-launch-1.0:17411): CRITICAL **: gst_video_meta_unmap_vaapi_memory: assertion 'mem->surface' failed

** (gst-launch-1.0:17411): CRITICAL **: gst_video_meta_unmap_vaapi_memory: assertion 'mem->surface' failed

** (gst-launch-1.0:17411): CRITICAL **: gst_video_meta_unmap_vaapi_memory: assertion 'mem->surface' failed
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:02.419777862
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

## My pipeline:

```
rtspsrc -> decodebin -> autovideosink
```

Is this packaging problem or I did something wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

According to http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/h264parse-has-been-removed-from-gstreamer-1-0-td4671468.html , the `h264parse` filter is now part of `libgstvideoparsersbad`.

I've made sure that `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers` is installed, and now everything works. The filter itself was renamed to 'legacyh264parse', but there's an alias for the old name so it should just work.

Comment: i had to `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`  to get it working